# Testing a Redux connected component with enzyme and jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am unit testing my React app with jest and enzyme and all is good until I happened to test a class component connected with Redux. I went ahead and tested it by wrapping the component with a  and then shallow mounting it. However I am not able to run assertions after updating the props of component, nor I am able to spy on the class methods being called or not.

Below is my sample code:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <TestComponent {...props}  />
    </Provider>
).dive();
```

Now when I try t set the props of the wrapper and run assertions, it fails:

```
wrapper.setProps({
  showHeader:  true
})
expect(wrapper.find('h1')).toHaveLength(1);
```

Interesting part is, if I export the unconnected component as also [suggested](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests/#connected-components) in redux docs, the assertions work well. Is it fine to export the unconnected component just for the purpose of testing? I can't spy on instance methods/lifecycle methods if I try to test the connected component.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `connect` function from `react-redux` to return the original component

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
   connect: () => Component => Component
}))
```